# bsoncxx: document::view vs document::value

Tags: c++, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

Please explain the difference between `bsoncxx::document::value` and `bsoncxx::document::view`. Is `view` just a proxy to `value` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bsoncxx library, `values` represent ownership of an immutable resource, but not the ability to inspect the owned resource. To inspect the owned resource, you obtain a `view` from the `value`. The `view` and `value` here are analogous to the relationship between `std::string` and `std::string_view`. By separating the aspects of ownership from inspection, we can have a cheap type used for APIs that only need to look at data, and a more expensive API for when we need to make copies or take over ownership of resources.

Comment: PS: Note that a `view` does *not* extend the lifetime of the underlying `value`. The lifetimes of all `views` derived from a given `value` must be subsets of the lifetime of the owning `value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `view` is a proxy for `value`.